# Hooking up a home theater system with both analog and digital devices?

Tags: home-theater

Last night I tried hooking up the new AV Receiver [Yamaha rx-v477] that I bought for my dad, but I had trouble getting a video signal from his old DVD player. This is the basic setup:

*Devices going into the receiver:*

- Cable box [HDMI video + audio] -> HDMI2.
- Chromecast [HDMI video + audio] -> HDMI6.
- DVD player [Component video + Optical audio] -> AV1

Then I plugged the receiver into the TV via HDMI. I got audio from everything, and video from everything except the DVD player! I tried using composite from the DVD player to the receiver and had the same issue; no video, only sound..

I'm going to work on it more today, but I thought I'd seek advice first. So, how can I hook this up correctly? I was under the impression that the receiver would handle all the various input devices and simply send video to the HDTV via HDMI and audio to the speakers. Do I need more than just a single HDMI connection from the receiver to the HDTV in this type of setup?

Comment: -1 because I believe this is getting off topic for the site.

Comment: This is an A/V troubleshooting question, not a home improvement question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same receiver and hit this problem when initially setting it up as well.

Essentially, the receiver outputs the video signal in the same format as the input, so: for HDMI inputs use the HDMI output, for component inputs use the monitor out (component) jacks, and for composite inputs use the monitor out (video) jack.  For your scenario, you'll need to have a component video connection to the TV as well to show the video from your DVD player.

This isn't made very clear in the [manual](http://download.yamaha.com/api/asset/file/?language=en&site=usa.yamaha.com&asset_id=61958), but you can find information about it on page 19 under the "Component / composite video connection" section.

Answer (score 2):

Lehmann is 100% correct, that means your receiver does not have a converter/upscaler inside so you will only be able to view the dvd player on the component OUT, it cannot upscale to a digital format.